# Combining a for loop with meta characters

Tags: r

Im writing a for loop that checks whether values in a particular column match a predefined list.

So it's kind of like this:

```
 money <- read.csv2("money.csv", header = T)
 #set counter
 count_financial = 1

 #set list
 financial_items <- c("bank", "ABN Amro")

 for (i in 1:nrow(money)) {
  if(money$Description[i] in financial_items ) {
   count_financial = count_financial + 1
  }
 }
```

It's working for now but I actually want to tweak it a little and use metacharacters. So I cant only find items which say "Bank" or "ABN Amro" but also lines which "bank cost" or "ABN Amro transaction".

Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
length(financial_items %in% money$Description)
```

But if you are intent on using the loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(money)) {
  if(money$Description[i] %in% financial_items ) {
   count_financial = count_financial + 1
  }
 }
```

**Update:**

Upon rereading the question, I think you are looking for:

```
length(grep("bank|abn amro", money$Description, ignore.case=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
filtered <- money[grep("bank|ABN Amro",money$Description,ignore.case=TRUE),]
count_financial <- nrow(filtered)
```